# How to call bootstrap modal from MVC controller class

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

in my jsp page I have to pass start date and expiry date  in the into controller class .and then using that dates I filtered data in Impl class .but the thing is when passing date into controller also I need to show that data in a bootstrap modal

this is my jsp form in page after button click those date goto the controller class

```
<table id="default-datatable" data-plugin="DataTable"
                                                                class="table table-striped" cellspacing="0"
                                                                width="100%">
                                                                <thead>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <th>Season</th>
                                                                        <th>Start date</th>
                                                                        <th>End date</th>
                                                                        <th>Activate Season</th>

                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </thead>

                                                                <tbody>
                                                                <c:forEach var="element" items="${seasons}">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                <form action="season.create" method="POST">




                                                                            <td>${element.seasonName}</td>
                                                                            <td>${element.startDate}</td>
                                                                            <td>${element.endDate}</td>

                                                                            <%-- <td><a data-toggle="modal"
                                                                                data-id="${element.seasonId}" title="Add this item"
                                                                                class="open-AddBookDialog btn btn-info"
                                                                                href="#myModal">Select Offer</a></td> --%>


                                                                                <td>
                                                                                <input type="hidden" name="startDate"
                                                                                    id="startDate" value="${element.startDate}"></input>
                                                                                <input type="hidden" name="expiryDate"
                                                                                    id="expiryDate" value="${element.endDate}"></input><input type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary"
                                                style="width: 90%; margin-top: 10px;" 
                                             name="action" value="Add" onclick="showDiv()"></td>
```

and my controller class method shown in bellow

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/season.create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createSeason(@ModelAttribute("Offer") Offer offer, BindingResult result,@RequestParam String action,@RequestParam("startDate") String startDate,
    @RequestParam("expiryDate") String expiryDate,  Map<String, Object> map, HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        System.out.println("testing -----------");
        int merchantId = 11;
        switch (action.toLowerCase()) {
        case "add":
             offerservice.getAlloffers(merchantId,startDate,expiryDate);
            System.out.println("inside season.create test strat date "+startDate+"enddate"+expiryDate);
            System.out.println("exDate"+expiryDate);
        //map.put("offerFilterd", offerservice.getAlloffers(merchantId));
            //map.put("offers", offerservice.getAlloffers(merchantId));
            map.put("offers", offerservice.getAlloffers(merchantId,startDate,expiryDate));

            map.put("seasons", offerservice.getAllSeasons(merchantId));
            map.put("Offer", new Offer());
            map.put("SeasonTypes", new SeasonTypes());

            map.put("editSingleImage", false);
            map.put("imageGalary", false);
            map.put("video", false);

            break;
        case "edit":

            break;
        case "delete":

            break;
        case "search":

            break;
        }

        //map.put("offers", offerservice.getAlloffers(merchantId));
        map.put("offers", offerservice.getAlloffers(merchantId,startDate,expiryDate));
        map.put("seasons", offerservice.getAllSeasons(merchantId));
        map.put("Offer", new Offer());


        map.put("editSingleImage", false);
        map.put("imageGalary", false);
        map.put("video", false);

        return "create-offer";
    }
```

this is my boostrap modal which include in the jsp page.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="display:none;">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Select Offer</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table id="default-datatable" data-plugin="DataTable"
                                class="table table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <p>form has submitted</p>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>

                                        <th>Offer Heading</th>
                                        <th>Offer Description</th>
                                        <th>Issue Date</th>
                                        <th>Expiration date</th>
                                        <th>Offer Discount </th>
                                        <th>Offer Price </th>
                                        <th>Allocated Points </th>
                                        <th>OfferClaim LImit</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>

                                <tbody>

                                    <c:forEach var="element" items="${offers}">
                                            <form:form action="offer.bind" method="POST" commandName="SeasonTypes" id="formID"> 
                            <tr>

                                <form:hidden path="seasonId" id="bookId" class="form-control normtxtin"/>
                            <%--    <td><form:input path="offerId" name="offerid" value="${element.offerid}" class="form-control normtxtin"/></td> --%>

                                <td>${element.offerSubheading}</td>
                                <td>${element.offerDescription}</td>    
                                <td>${element.issueDateTime}</td>
                                <td>${element.expiryDate}</td>
                                <td>${element.offerDiscount}</td>
                                <td>${element.offerPrice}</td>
                                <td>${element.pointsAllocated}</td>
                                <td>${element.offerClaimLimit}</td>
                                <td><input type="hidden" id="offerId" name="offerid" type="text" value="${element.offerid}"/></td>
                                <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%;font-size:16px;padding:10px;" name="action" value="Add">Select Offer</button></td>
                            </tr>
                        </form:form> 
                                    </c:forEach>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

and this is my java script code

```
<script> function showDiv() {       $('#myModal').modal('show') }
 </script>
```

here is my DAOIMPL methord

```
public List <Offer> getAlloffers(int merchantId,String sDate,String ExDate){
        System.out.println("sDate"+sDate+ "EndDate"+ExDate);
        Long merchantIdLng = (long) merchantId;
        List<Offer> offers= sessionfactory.openSession().createQuery("From Offer where merchant ="+merchantIdLng+"and issueDateTime  BETWEEN '"+sDate+"' AND'"+ ExDate+"'" ).list();

        return offers;

    }
```

but after button click it didn't show the bootstrap modal. If any one can tell Why is my code dose not work. I need to pass date and filter the data and show in a modal when the button click

Comment: what's your exact problem? is it that you can't open your modal or what ?

Comment: yes i can't open my modal when button click, without form submit ,is there have any option like ajax.I like to know how this done by using ajax

Comment: no need for ajax to open your modal. the use of ajax is for getting data from server side.

Answer (score 1):

here's the same code that you used. Except I added bootstrap and jquery:

```js
function showDiv(){
 $('#myModal').modal();

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<input type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" id="showDivBtn"
style="width: 90%; margin-top: 10px;" name="action" value="Add" onclick="showDiv()">
                                             
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="display:none;">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
<!-  your modal contain -!>
        </div>
</div>
```